# how to write c# code in sitecore rules contenteditor

Tags: c#, sitecore

[image]

I am trying to write C# in Item saved event of Script item Code Field, as shown in the attached image.

My question is can we write C# code in this field and if it is possible what syntax should I follow?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, yes you are able to add your own custom code.

The `Type` field is where you would define your `using` in your class. You will want to add any additional namespaces your code needs here.

The `Code` field then contains all C# code within and including the `namespace` declaration. This is where you can define your properties, methods etc.

As this is a rule you are creating you need to define a Sitecore rule as follows.

```
namespace UserAction
{
   public class NewUserAction<T> : RuleAction<T> where T : RuleContext
   {
      public override void Apply(T ruleContext)
      {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(ruleContext, "ruleContext");

      }
   }
}
```

In terms of syntax / guidelines you will need to adhere to standard C# synatax and follow best practices of .NET and Sitecore.

I would recommend writing the code in Visual Studio for ease of use. Once you are sure it works and compiles copy the `usings` into the `Type` field and the the code within the `namespace` declaration and the `namespace` itself into the `Code` field.